# how to reply the ratings with comments in face book page in C# using facebook supported api

Tags: c#, facebook

i'm developing a web application using c# for the following .Considered a face book page for e.g. restaurant in which customers visit the page and give ratings with comments . Now i need to reply these comments using face book api. any suggestion to achieve this.

I have access token and used the following  "GET /v2.7/{page-id}/ratings HTTP/1.1" to retrieve the ratings data.
The output of the above get method will provide the ratings 3 stars, 4 starts etc with comments and the unique page id , date time etc. i tried but i was not able to find the solution to reply comments given along with ratings.

I was able to reply using api for the posts posted in walls by customer . but the reply to the reviews with comments driving me hard. Any suggestions or guidance will be appreciated and useful.

Answer (score 0):

field=open_graph_story is the option available to get the object contains public reviews and id.
 to retrieve : {page-id}/ratings?field=open_graph_story
 to post     :(POST) {object-id}/comments